# DataTable does not show

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use JQuery DataTables. I follow the explanations on datatables.net website but I do something wrong.

I use a base.html that load bootstrap and jQuery but I have an error.

> jQuery is not defined

If I look browser debug console, I can see jQuery is loaded.
jQuery DataTables code is loaded at the page loading so it should be OK.

test.html

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block extrahead %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

{% endblock %}
{% block title %}Randomization | Intense TBM{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class='container'>

    <h1>DataTable</h1>
    <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

{% endblock %}
{% block extrabody %}
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
{% load static %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">


{% block extrahead %}{% endblock %}

    <title>{% block title %}Mereva{% endblock %}</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    {% include 'layouts/_nav.html' %}     
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {% include 'layouts/_footer.html' %}
    <!--09/11/2019 : config qui fonctionne-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--09/11/2019 : config qui fonctionne-->

{% block extrabody %}{% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you are typing in tags, descriptions of the tags matched show up below the tags box. Please read those descriptions. `datatable` refers to a .NET class, not the jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It normally that the code doesn't work, you need to import jquery. the order is important:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put JQuery declaration just before JQquery script (see below)
thanks again

```
{% extends 'layouts/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block extrahead %}
<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> -->

{% endblock %}
{% block title %}Randomization | Intense TBM{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class='container'>

    <h1>DataTable</h1>
    <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

{% endblock %}
{% block extrabody %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
{% endblock %}
```